# Increasing the efficiency of when looping over a user defined function which requires multiple dataframes as arguments

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I apologise if this is an extremely simple question but I do not seem to be able to find a workable solution. I have created a function which requires three inputs, two data frames and a single value. I need to run this function multiple times with the same inputs, but a different seed. I have managed to create a for loop, like the one below, that does what I need but it is really slow. I was wondering if there is any way of increasing the speed of this loop. I have tried to use lapply and purr::map but I do not seem to be able to get the multiple inputs in as required.

```
#Simple example version of the code I have for demonstration
library(dplyr)
exampe_function <- function(df1 ,df2, singlevalue){
  df3 <- sample_frac(df1, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
  temp <- df3[1] + df2[1]
  out <- temp[1,1] * singlevalue #Only need a single value
  return(out)
}

example_df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
example_df2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
singlevalue <- 0.5

test <- exampe_function(example_df1, example_df2, singlevalue)

test_list <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(i)
  t <- exampe_function(example_df1, example_df2, singlevalue)
  test_list <- c(test_list, t)
}

unlist(test_list)
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Reproducible example please. What package are you using? Put the correct `library` statement at the start of your code.

Comment: Is `exampe_function` your real function? Very likely the bottleneck is not the `for` loop, but rather the function call itself. You should work to optimize it. No `purrr::map` or other wrappers will give you better performances.

Comment: @nicola the `example_function` follows the same structure as my real function. The real function I create a glm with the first data frame and predict it onto the second data frame using: `model_glm <- glm(num_burrows ~ elevation + slope, 
                   data = df1, family="poisson") prediction = predict(df2, model_glm)`